# Matlab IIR stopband filter attenuates my sinusoid input with frequency in the passband

Tags: matlab, filter-design, infinite-impulse-response, digital-filters, attenuation

I'm a DSP newbie trying to get into the field. Despite being able to use some of the MATLAB tools, I'm still not completely solid on some intuition of the frequency domain.

I've implemented a biquad Chebyshev type 2 filter in direct form II using `design()` and `fdesign()`, and cascaded an all pass filter before it to make sure the phase is approximately linear using `iirgrpdelay()`

[image]

Here are my filter coefficients.
The cascade filter is made up of two stages; the first is an all-pass equalizing filter and the second is my band-stop filter.

```
Stage 1 SOSMatrix:

   0.381213874783434  -1.557955120504960   1.591776409857931   1.000000000000000  -0.978752487382327   0.239489586868207
   0.552531400073819  -0.022041931397907   0.944632862505602   1.000000000000000  -0.023333860458169   0.584916555420538
   0.208375162206942   0.338597008794322   0.403080816836635   1.000000000000000   0.840022632313836   0.516956286439685
   0.738077366524991   2.000000000000000   1.498774195719990   1.000000000000000   1.334423828293380   0.492454012507487

Stage 1 ScaleValues:

   0.260737099485881
   1.000000000000000
   1.000000000000000
   1.000000000000000
   4.222053367426932
   
Stage 2 SOSMatrix:

   1.000000000000000  -1.649455187829982   1.000000000000000   1.000000000000000  -1.104541883178642   0.913753853150600
   1.000000000000000  -1.264410719232027   1.000000000000000   1.000000000000000  -1.653222532296871   0.943601232271565
   1.000000000000000  -1.611538275581591   1.000000000000000   1.000000000000000  -1.117951080612895   0.785871033092721
   1.000000000000000  -1.329923547522389   1.000000000000000   1.000000000000000  -1.524529858509588   0.841251385596782
   1.000000000000000  -1.536278103762843   1.000000000000000   1.000000000000000  -1.372242531855038   0.762644118662937
   1.000000000000000  -1.433307330009434   1.000000000000000   1.000000000000000  -1.221557613144382   0.735502467713962

Stage 2 ScaleValues:
   
   0.954605779388083
   0.954605779388083
   0.901497869853696
   0.901497869853696
   0.873798810487316
   0.873798810487316
   1.000000000000000
```

The frequency response looks according to the spec., but my input is coming out attenuated. I should put a legend here but the blue line is the input and yellow line the output.

[image]

Here's how I'm constructing my sinusoidal input; the amplitude is -6dB full-scale and its frequency is set to 0.01. My filter sampling frequency is 1MHz, and it's to my understanding that this sinusoid should be within the passband.

```
% Generate input
% input attenuation; <db> and <absolute value>
input_att_db = -6;
input_att_ab = 10 ^ (input_att_db / (-20));

% input sinusoid with angular frequency w0 for L samples
f0 = 0.01;
w0 = 2 * pi * f0;
L = 1000;
n = 0:L - 1;
input = sin(w0 * n) / input_att_ab;
```

I'm then just calling the filter as if its a function. I named my filter `cas` short for "cascade".

```
outputi = cas(input);
plot(n, outputi)
```

Is this normal? If not what could I be doing wrong?
Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: Generally your code looks ok. Your signal frequency isn't where you think it is but it's still in the pass band. so this unexpected behavior.

Comment: It's hard to tell as long as we don't know what exactly `cas()` is doing.

Comment: @MattL. cas() is my filter, short for "cascade"; I saw it used this way in this matlab documentation for biquad iir filters.
https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/dsp.biquadfilter-system-object.html
It's down in the first example, could I be messing up here?

Comment: @Hilmar Any idea where I could be messing up? Or is there anything else I could provide to help you diagnose?

Comment: @ChrisH.: I don't know but I don't see any other possibility where things might have gone wrong.

Comment: I would just use the `filter` function with the coefficients you've computed; this is much more transparent (at least for me) than what you're doing now. Might there be some hidden scaling for implementation purposes?

Comment: Add the filter coefficients of the Chebyshev filter and of the allpass filter to your question, otherwise we'll keep guessing.

Comment: @MattL. will do! I've added them in my original post; both the sosmatrix and the scale values

Comment: @MattL. I'm trying `filter` as you suggested; how would you go about cascading two filters in this case? I'm feeding the output of my all-pass into my band-stop filter, thereby "cascading" them. In this case my total output actually gets amplified from ~+-0.5 pk-pk, to ~+-0.8pk-pk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the filter coefficients and scaling values to check whether the filters work as expected. Assuming that your SOS matrices are stored in the variables `sos1` and `sos2`, and that the corresponding scaling values are in the arrays `scale1` and `scale2`, the output can be computed by

```
g1 = prod(scale1);
g2 = prod(scale2);
y = g1 * sosfilt(sos1,input);
y = g2 * sosfilt(sos2,y);
```

Using your input signal, I get the following plot for the output signal:

[image]

This is exactly what one would expect. This means that the additional scaling that you see must happen somewhere in the blackbox `cas()`. The filters themselves do what you intend them to do.

**EDIT:**

The delay of a sinusoidal input signal is determined by the phase delay of the filter, not by the group delay. Phase delays of concatenated filters simply add up. The phase delay of a filter with frequency response $H(e^{j\omega})$ is given by

$$\tau_p=-\frac{\textrm{arg}\big\{H(e^{j\omega})\big\}}{\omega},\qquad\omega\neq 0$$

where $\textrm{arg}\big\{H(e^{j\omega})\big\}$ is the filter's phase response.

You can compute the phase delay at the input frequency $\omega_0$ using the following Matlab/Octave code:

```
[b1,a1] = sos2tf(sos1,g1);
[b2,a2] = sos2tf(sos2,g2);
H1 = polyval( b1, exp(1i*w0) ) / polyval( a1, exp(1i*w0) );
H2 = polyval( b2, exp(1i*w0) ) / polyval( a2, exp(1i*w0) );
tp1 = - angle(H1) / w0;
tp2 = - angle(H2) / w0;
tp1 + tp2    % total phase delay
```

The total phase delay at the input frequency $\omega_0$ is about $9.4$ samples, which agrees with your observation.

Note that not only the allpass filter but also the bandstop filter contributes to the phase delay

Comment: The amplitude is fixed now, thank you! But there seems to be a delay of around 9 samples compared to the input; is this expected for iir filters or filters in general? I thought it would be correlated to the group delay specification I set for the all pass filter to meet, and to my surprise the more lax my group delay spec. is the smaller the delay at the output. Group delays within [4, 7, 10, 13, 16], correspond to output delays [20, 19, 9, 2, 3].

Comment: @ChrisH.: I'll edit my answer to address the delay. What was the issue with the amplitude scaling?

Comment: I feel stupid even admitting this, but when one calls a dsp.FilterCascade as a function, what matlab actually does is return the filter's step function. The "input" becomes the time vector the step response is evaluated at. It's even noted in the documentation page I was referencing; "Note: If you are using R2016a or an earlier release, replace each call to the object with the equivalent step syntax. For example, obj(x) becomes step(obj,x)."

Comment: @ChrisH.: Ok, strange ... If you look at my updated answer you'll see that a delay of about 9 samples at the input frequency is exactly what one would expect.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for thorough response. I plotted `grpdelay(cas)`(`cas` being my filter), and the point at w0 ~= 0.011 corresponds to a delay of ~9.38, which also corroborates your result.

Answer (score 0):

Either

**1.-** Aliasing is taking place, because chosen `fs` sampling frequency too low, let's assume it's not the case

or

**2.-** Your filter stop-band and the input signal are on same frequency because the displayed `fvtool` response is not frequency in `Hz` but `f/fs` no units.

The plotted 'frequency' in the response displayed in the question argued as `0.01Hz`  is not actually `0.01Hz` but  `f1/fs = 0.01` .

**3.-** Since the actual input carrier frequency is not mentioned why don't we try the following

```
bandstopSpecs = fdesign.bandstop('N,Fp1,Fst1,Fst2,Fp2,C',60,9.6e3,12.8e3,22.4e3,25.6e3,128000)

bandstopSpecs.Passband1Constrained = true;

bandstopSpecs.Apass1 = .1;

bandstopSpecs.Passband2Constrained = true;

bandstopSpecs.Apass2 = .1;

bandstopFilt = design(bandstopSpecs,'Systemobject',true)

fvtool(bandstopFilt)
```

**3.1.-** this is `fvtool` response in `Hz`

Now pull down the **Analysis menu** and choose **Analysis Parameters**

[image]

In this window tick the **normalized box** option:

[image]

**3.3.-** Observe that now the x-axis displays the same

'f x pi radian **/ SAMPLE**'

shown in the question

[image]

The x-axis is no longer in `Hz` , is it ?

The question originator assumed that the x-axis readings are Hz

**4.-** I suggest to do what we would do with a conventional desktop set-up :

Shift up and down the generator frequency and observe the filter output.

Rewording : Try sweeping input carrier `f1` from as low as possible up to let's say `fs/2` to avoid Aliasing.

One should then see at what frequencies the stop band really takes place.

Comment: The input frequency is definitely not in the filter's stopband.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for the comment. Please read my reworded answer.